# How does the accounts.firefox.com sign in page change the href?

Tags: javascript, html5-history

Steps:

1. Visit the following website: https://accounts.firefox.com/signin
2. If you are already logged in, select "Use a different account" from the bottom.
3. At the bottom of this sign in page you will find a link to "Create an account", select the link.
4. Now that you are on the sign up page, select the "Have an account? Sign in" link at the bottom to navigate back to sign in.

Navigating back and forth between these two "sign in" and "sign up" pages causes the `location.href` to alternate between https://accounts.firefox.com/signin and https://accounts.firefox.com/signup. I can see the DOM change as well.

How are these navigation events occurring? Monitoring the network tab in my dev tools I do not see any new `GET` request for the new page. It appears to be a SPA that is using the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). However, monitoring `window.addEventListener('popstate', function() { console.log('page changed!'); });` does not fire anything.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @epascarello I referenced the history API in my question. Isn't the `popstate` event suppose to fire when that occurs?